# Identifying an unknown function in an exponential function

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, least-squares

I encounter the following question and I cannot find a correct solution. Consider a regression with cross-sectional data:

$$y_i=c+e^{m(x_i)}+u_i,$$

where for $i=1,...,n$, the scalar $y_i$ is the dependent variable, $c$ is constant number, $m(\cdot)$ is an unknown but univariate smoothing function of $x_i\in R$, and $u_i$ is mean-zero error term satisfying $E(u|x)=0$. Clearly, $E(y|x)=c+e^{m(x)}$.

**Question:** How to consistently identify $m(x_i)$ for all $i=1,..,n$ from the above regression?

I have tried an estimator of $m(x_i)$ through a combination of local linear estimator and nonlinear least square estimator. Specifically, I take the first-order Taylor expansion to $m(x_i)$ around a particular point $x$, so that $m(x_i) \approx m(x)+(x_i-x)m'(x) $, where $m'(x)\equiv \frac{\partial m(x_i)}{\partial x}$.  Then I select the estimator of $[m(x),m'(x)]$ by $[\hat{m}(x),\hat{m}'(x)]\equiv [\hat{\alpha}_0,\hat{\alpha}_1]$, together with $\hat{c}$ the estimator of the constant term $c$, by minimizing the following objective function:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left[y_i-c-e^{\alpha_0+(x_i-x)\alpha_1} \right]^2k\left(\frac{x_i-x}{h}\right),$$

where the function $k\left(\frac{x_i-x}{h}\right)$ is a univariate kernel function, such as standard normal p.d.f.. Hence, the above estimators $(\hat{c},\hat{\alpha}_0,\hat{\alpha}_1)$ need to be obtained through nonlinear least square, where the unknown function $m(\cdot)$ is estimated by local linear estimator.

However, I find that the function $m(x_i)$ cannot be identified well through simulation, unless $c=0$, i.e., there is no constant term.

Can anyone share with me your thoughts regarding how to estimate the unknown function $m(\cdot)$ nonparametrically in the present set-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question above can be actually solved using the local nonlinear least square estimator (LNLS) by Gozalo and Linton (2000), *Journal of Econometrics*. My above solution is not feasible because one cannot identify the unknown function in the presence of the constant term $c$.

Alternatively, instead of approximating the unknown smoothing function $m(x)$ in $e^{m(x)}$ through local linear estimator, we use some parametric regression information as a pilot estimator, say, $m(x)$ may be closer to $b_0x+b_1x^2$. If the pilot information is correct, the LNLS estimator behaves the same as a parametric estimator. If the pilot information is incorrect, then the LNLS estimator behaves as a consistent nonparametric estimator. The LNLS estimator is unbiased when the parametric information is correct, and is consistent in both cases.